# SQLite open helper to initialize a few entries

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to programming. I'm making an Android app and I am at a new hurtle.  I am using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class to manage my database.  Its been great, I am able to create tables, add entries and all that good stuff.

The problem I have is that for one of my tables I want to have an initial 7 entries that keep the same ID and can be replaced by the user. My plan is to use a `SQLiteDatabase.replace()` method in order to replace these entries. Since I want the entries to be set by me and then edited by the user, that means I want to add entries using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class so that these entries are set only when the user installs the app and creates the database. *I do not want to make a pre-populated database that I must include in the install package.*

My Java skills are god awful so my main question is **how do I add entries from inside my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class?** I already know how to add entries in my other classes using the following method that I made:

```
public long createCategoriesSQLEntry(String name) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_CATEGORIES, name);
    return myDatabase.insert(StringCategory_Table, null, cv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `onCreate()` in the database helper.  Like this.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            if(db.isOpen()){
                //create tables here
                db.execSQL("create table");
                db.execSQL("insert row");
                db.execSQL("insert row");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could also use the db.Insert() in place of the db.execSQL().

Comment: you sir, are my hero.  worked like a charm. didn't know i could just add rows in the class like that.  Now does the actual database get created when the SQLiteClass object is created in one of my activities? what if that activity that creates that object is never executed?

Comment: You are welcome!  You will have to call the Sqlhelper class at some point for it to create the database.  The way I address it, is to let the database be created when the user does something that instantiates the database for the first time.

Comment: Some more info about the SQLiteOpenHelper is located here....http://10keyes.blogspot.com/2012/08/android-implementing-sqliteopenhelper.html

Answer (score -1):

You are database will be installed when for the first time your application is installed. So, you write you data either in file and load it on onCreate method in SQLiteHandling class or just write the data in your java and call it in onCreated method like CyberTengu said.